# apache low memory error

Tags: apache, low-memory

mod_python(?) is eating a lot of ram (about 9mb per worker process). If i open several TRAC pages at once many of them will have an error due to no ram (64mb virtual limit). if i limit the worker threads to 3 i can get by alright. Problem is if no one is accessing TRAC i have A LOT of ram being unused.

Is there a way i can either

1. Limit the amount of worker process that can use python?
2. Limit the amount of worker process in my trac path?
3. Have apache spawn as many worker process or threads it wants but have it only spawn when X amount or ram is free (or when X amount or below is in use by apache)
4. Something else ?

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault

Comment: tinkertim: Sure does, too bad it didnt exist at the time of writing :X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could configure a second `mod_python` apache with minimal worker threads to run only on the local interface and with a different port, i.e. http://127.0.0.1:9000/. Then for your public apache instance on port 80, disable mod_python and tune for optimal ram utilization. Proxy all trac and other python app requests to the local `mod_python` instance.

If the public facing apache is left only to serve static content, then consider replacing it with something lightweight such as [nginx](http://nginx.net/) or [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/).